# In javascript how to create more than one clone with less code like the clone() method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`clone()` method in jQuery:

```
var imgElement = $('<img src="img.png"/>').clone();
        $(imgElement).appendTo('#ulSelector1 li');
    $(imgElement).appendTo('#ulSelector2 li');
    $(imgElement).appendTo('#ulSelector3 li');
```

so i tried the `cloneNode()` method in javascript:

```
var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
    imgElement.setAttribute("src", "img.png");
    imgElement.cloneNode(true);

    var selector1 = document.querySelector("#img1 li");
        selector1.insertBefore(imgElement, selector1[0]);
    var selector2 = document.querySelector("#img2 li");
        selector2.appendChild(imgElement);
    var selector3 = document.querySelector("#img3 li");
        selector3.appendChild(imgElement);
```

but the `cloneNode()` method only create one clone.
so in javascript how to create more than one clone with less code or without adding more cloneNode method like the `clone()` method in jQuery.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. What is the problem with your pure client-side javascript code?

Comment: Why not wrapping the clone statement in a for loop ?

Comment: Your first code snippet also clones a single element, then proceeds to relocate it thrice under different parents. The two snippets are technically equivalent.

Comment: There are answers posted can you give them feedback

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to append 3 new elements to your HTML page, you will anyway need to either create 3 new elements or clone them. Instead of creating an element and cloning it, you can simply instruct jQuery to generate a new element every time:

```
var pattern = '<img src="img.png"/>';
$(pattern).appendTo('#ulSelector1 li');
$(pattern).appendTo('#ulSelector2 li');
$(pattern).appendTo('#ulSelector3 li');
```

It will create 3 new DOM elements and append them to corresponding elements.

Comment: sorry about that, but how to create more clone in javascript without adding more cloneNode method?

Comment: @Mr.PM It does not make sense. Just imagine the non-working code or pseudoode that you want ("I want something like this:") and write it. I just can't imagine the usage of "more clones" without "cloneNode`. And what's wrong with the approach in my answer? 3 lines for 3 items is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
var img = $('<img src="img.png"/>');

$(img.clone()).appendTo('#ulSelector1 li');
$(img.clone()).appendTo('#ulSelector2 li');
$(img.clone()).appendTo('#ulSelector3 li');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop structure like this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i<4;i++){
     var img =  $('<img src="img.png"/>');
     img.appendTo('#ulSelector'+i + ' li');
 }
```

You don´t need `clone()`-Method here and your `var imgElement` is already a jQuery-Object. So you don´t need the `$()` either,